# Detect browser Back Button VS Reload/Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

`window.onbeforeunload = goodbye;`

I currently use the code above to detect the `onbeforeunload` event, but I'm wondering if there is a way to use the event object that was passed in to determine if the event was fired due to the back button being pressed or if it was from the user attempting to reload the page.

There is no life or death scenario here as Chrome (possibly others) tailors the text of the button.

I'd simply like to the tailor the message that I display...and it's bugging me that I can't find it when looking through the object in Chrome.

Comment: You can do that on the server-side checking the headers. Although js has the window reference also.

Comment: There is no server action involved here. I'm using `History.js` to push a state. The back button only fires the event once they are about to leave the form. The refresh ALWAYS first (as I would expect).

Comment: The event object itself has no pointer to what event action caused it, so there is no inherent want to determine between back/forward, pushstate, etc. You could roll your own breadcrumb module and use it to determine if the url you're going to is the same as the one you're on, which might suggest a refresh.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I guess I'm not sure how hot to get the destination url?